# Comparing two tables in laravel to check if a row exists in the tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Very quick one, I have this school project I'm working on but something seems to me a problem.

**I have:**

Table A - for fees:

```
id | feename | fee_level | fee_acad_year
```

Table B - for paid fees:

`id | fee_id | student_number | payment_status`

So what I'm trying to do is that, I want to loop through the fees table for all the fees and then go to the paid fees table to check if the `fee_id` exists there regarding to the student's number and where the payment status is only 1 i.e paid.

If the `fee_id` is present it should mark them as paid the paid ones and store them in an array as the paid one.

Then if it doesnt exists it should store them in another array as not paid ones.

Here is my code:

```
// Fetch All fees for that level, semester and acamedic year 
        $fees = DB::table('fee')
            ->where([
                ['fee.Department','=',$csl->departmentid],
                ['fee.Semester','=',$csl->semesterid],
                ['fee.StudentLevel','=',$csl->levelid]
            ])
            ->select('id')
            ->get();
    }

    //return $fees;

    $feeids = array();
    foreach($fees as $fee){
        $feeids[] = $fee->id;
    }
    //dd($feeids);

    // Select all from paid fees
    $paidFees = PaidFees::all();

    $paidFeeIds = array();
    foreach($paidFees as $pd) {
        $paidFeeIds[] = $pd->FeeId;
    }
    $status = "";
    if(in_array($feeids, $paidFeeIds)) {

        $status = "paod";
    }else {
        $status = "Not Paid";
    }
```

This is the part where I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need an array of paid fees IDs and an array of not paid fees IDs, you can use Eloquent.

First, define a relationship:

```
public function paidFees()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PaidFees::class, 'fee_id');
}
```

Then get IDs:

```
$paidFeesIds = Fee::whereHas('paidFees', function($q) {
    $q->where('payment_status', 1);
})->pluck('id')->toArray();

$notPaidFeesIds = Fee::whereNotIn('id', $paidFeesIds)->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Comment: I have the Paid Fees Model, should i define the relationship there or in the controller or which Model i'm i going to define the relationship in, I have two models, 1. PaidFees and 2. Fee

Comment: @AdewumiGabriel you need to define it in `Fee` model.

Comment: Ok i got the IDs but can you explain what that code does

Comment: It worked!!!!! So Happy, Have been debugging since 4 days ago, though i'm new to the language

Comment: Had a almost similar usecase, worked perfectly. Thank you @AlexeyMezenin